# Memory after recreated NSMutableArray reinitialized

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a class that mimics the behavior of the `UIImagePickerController` except with some subtle differences. In my class, I use only one view controller and use it to swap out the albums tableview and photos tableview when the user makes a row / thumbnail selection. So the sequence of events that is causing me problems is as follows:

1. I select an album
2. The photos tableview loads, and I push the back button to go back
   to the albums tableview
3. The albums tableview loads
4. I select an album, and now a memory access error triggers

I have implemented both of the tableviews and the array in ivars as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *selectAnAlbumTableView, *selectAPhotoTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *albums, *photos;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ALAssetsGroup *album;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
```

One difference between the albums tableview and the photos tableview is that the photos tableview is recreated each time a user selects an album and this is where the error occurs. Initially, the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" was occurring when I was removing the tableview, like I do here:

```
        [[self selectAPhotoTableView] removeFromSuperview];
        [selectAPhotoTableView release];
        selectAPhotoTableView = nil;
        [photos release];
         photos = nil;
```

I noticed the error is occurring at `[photos release]`. Photos is the array where I store all of the thumbnail buttons that are put in cells on the photos tableview. If I remove `[photos release]` and photos = nil, then the problem occurs when the tableview is actually created (as I mentioned initially):

```
NSMutableArray *photosTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self setPhotos: photosTemp];
[photosTemp release];
```

Now the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" is being thrown after the `[self setPhotos: photosTemp];` line. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

UPDATE: I put the wrong code for where the error occurs the second time, now it's fixed.

Comment: could we see the error please? Also the @property statements for the ivars

Comment: @Max MacLeod I've added what you requested in the post. The error was "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and the property statements are listed above. Thanks for your inquiry.

Comment: Could you enable zombies and see if it fires a message sent to deallocated instance error? Enable zombies in xcode4 by editing your scheme, and checking the zombies enabled checkbox under diagnostics

Comment: @MaxMacleod Hey Max, I did what you asked and in the console right before the error is shown I got "2011-10-20 04:55:31.304 CustomImagePicker[21510:307] *** -[UIImage isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x197850"

Comment: @MaxMacleod Thanks that helped me figure out what the problem was. For some reason this line was causing the leak: thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[theALAsset thumbnail]]; Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: yeah it is "@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *thumbnailImage;", I am setting it in one of my classes initializer method

Comment: going to put something in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put this in an answer rather than a massive comment.

This line *(see comments)* will cause a problem:

```
thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[theALAsset thumbnail]];
```

That's because`thumbnailImage`is an ivar.`UIImage imageWithCGImage`is returning you an autoreleased object. Therefore you must retain it either explicitly, as follows:

```
thumbnailImage = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[theALAsset thumbnail]] retain];
```

Or, you can let your property do it for you via the generated setters. Setting up a property  as follows won't do anything because in your line above you are referring to`thumbnailImage`directly, not via the setters.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *thumbnailImage;
```

What you need to do is use`self`, so you have:

```
self.thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[theALAsset thumbnail]];
```

That will go through generated setters that first checking for any existing object,`release`it if there is one, then do a`retain`on your newly assigned object. All that happens automatically. In other words, it saves you the bother of doing:

```
-(void)setThumbnailImage:(UIImage *)aThumbnailImage
{
    [aThumbnailImage retain];
    if (thumbnailImage)
    {
        [thumbnailImage release];
    }
    thumbnailImage = aThumbnailImage;
}
```

Aaron Hillegass' book has a great explanation of this stuff in "Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X".

A key thing to do is to run builds with the Analyzer, or just run the Analyzer from time to time. It will spot a lot of these issues before you get to the time consuming process of tracking down EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors.

Answer (score 0):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS means that you presented a pointer that isn't valid (and in this context `nil` can be considered "valid").  In your first case that bad pointer would appear to be `photos`.

If it were an auto variable it could be bad because you failed to initialize it, but the system always nulls instance variables.

So either you assigned something invalid to it, or the value that was in it is still there, but the object it addressed has been released.

The error in the second case is oddly suggesting that "self" has been released.  This could well be your root problem, and your `dealloc` method is releasing `photos`, so that shows the error first.  I'd suggest you place a NSLog in your `dealloc` routine to see if it's getting invoked too soon, and, if so, then obviously figure out how you failed to properly retain your controller object.